# ElasticSearch should (OR) condition not working

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nosql

**Read the edits below**!
I have this query where I want to get the documents that have *eventType* exact equal to *"AgentFoo"* **OR** *eventType* exact equal to *"CustomerBar"*. I also have some *must_not* conditions and a date range filter:

```
GET _search
{"size": 100,
 "query": {
   "bool" : {
     minimum_should_match": 1,
     "should": [{ "term": { "eventType.keyword":"AgentFoo" }},
                { "term": { "eventType.keyword":"CustomerBar" }}
     
     ],
     "must_not" : [{"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "-456-999"}}},
                   {"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "teste"}}},
                   {"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "monitoracao"}}},
                   {"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "abc"}}},
                   {"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "def"}}},
                   {"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "ghi"}}}
                   ],
"filter": {
 "range": { "when": { "gte":"2019-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
           "lt"  :"2019-12-31T23:59:27.879Z" }}}
   }
}
}
```

For some reason, it returns only the documents that have *eventType* "CustomerBar". What is wrong here? The elasticSearch version is 6.3.1 and the event type and correlationId structures are:

```
"eventType": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }

"correlationId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
```

Thank you!

### EDIT1:

Analyzers may be the issue, so I edited the question to show the exact casing.

### EDIT2:

Err... I just sorted the *eventType* field and noticed that both events are showing up. Also, adding *minimum_should_match": 1* is important. I will accept anyone's answer that elaborate a bit on these points, since adding my own answer would be pointless. Thanks.

Comment: what is the `mapping` for `eventType` ? is it `text` or `keyword`?also if you can post a sample document

Comment: I added the event type mapping, I'll try to add a doc example.

Comment: @Fernando why did you use eventType.keyword instead of eventType ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I don't know, I'm basically trying to fix the query.

Comment: @Fernando What do you get if you remove `{ "match": { "eventType.keyword":"agent" }},` from `should` clause ?

Comment: could you provide a document sample from your index with eventType = agent? :) A document that should match your criteria. Cause your request seems totally fine.

Comment: The behavior of `should` in a `bool` query is a bit complicated. It is explained in the [6.x documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-bool-query.html) but not in the latest documentation (it still behave the same way though). Basically in your case the previous documentation stated that you have to set a `minimum_should_match` parameter to filter on the should queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your query I'd venture the reason you only get eventType.keyword "customer" in your results is that the must_not and filter parts of your query only return those.

You can easily confirm this by removing the "should" section of your query and run it.

Could you also confirm whether you wish to retrieve only the entries with eventType.keyword values "agent" or "customer"?

Because from what I (believe I) know , [this is not what your query is doing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html).
If either value is a requirement, you need to add the "minimum_should_match": 1 in there

Finally, could you also provide the mapping for correlationId? 
I believe this might also be cause for your unexpected result

**Edit based on the comments you made to your own question**

So your issue was that you only retrieved the first 100 results, and all of the entries in that subset where of only one eventType, while the total results included all of them.

As you also pointed out, and I mentionned earlier, that minimum_should_match is important or you're still might get other eventTypes than the two you wish to select. Without this parameter, *should* behaves like a "better match", the score of the entries that match that part of your query will be better than the others, but matching that part is not mandatory.

One point to also realize is that most likely the first entry in your must_not: `{"match": {"correlationId": {"query": "-456-999"}}}` is not doing what you expect: it's filtering out any correlationId that contains the "word" 456 or 999

You should read the information available on [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis.html).
To summarize quickly, a text field like correlationId is analyzed: by default split into words, based on whitespaces, dash, dot, comma, ...
And the same happens to queries on text fields when you use match.

So `-456-999` is split into `456` and `999`.
If these show up as words in the correlationId fields you query, they will all match, and so be removed from your selection.

I'd also propose rewriting your query, using [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to make it more readable.

The should part could be replaced with this:

```
"must": {
  "terms": {
    "eventType.keyword": [
      "agent",
      "customer"
    ]
  }
}
```

If correlationId is also an exact match, you could write it so:

```
"must_not": {
  "terms": {
    "correlationId.keyword": [
        "-456-999",
        "teste",
        "monitoracao",
        "abc",
        "def",
        "ghi"
    ]
  }
}
```

If an exact match is not what you require, you'll need to ensure the analysis aspect is clear to you to confirm the type of match you were aiming for. As it is, another format for what you seemed to aim for would be something similar to this:

```
{
  "must_not": [
    {
      "match_phrase": {
        "correlationId": "-456-999"
      }
    },
    {
      "match": {
        "correlationId": "teste monitoracao abc def ghi"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No, the must_not and filter are not excluding the eventType. I think It's a exact match/analyzer issue.

Comment: Yes, I want only these two types of events, plus the must not and date range.